English translation of Weyl's article "Quantenmechanik und Gruppentheorie"
Is there an English translation of Weyl's 1927 article Quantenmechanik und Gruppentheorie. Note that I do not mean the book of the same name.

If this is still a concern, here are some thoughts. Download a copy of the paper (if all else fails, it is in Weyl's collected works). OCR it using something like Textify. Then translate it (or what you need) using an online translator. Here is what one gets for the opening paragraph - not pro standard but probably good enough:
In quantum mechanics, two questions can be clearly separated from each other: 1. How do I get to the matrix, the Hermite form, which represents a given quantity in one of its constitution according to a known physical system? 2. Once the Hermite form is obtained, what is its physical meaning, what kind of physical statements can I get from it? On the second question, v. Neumann gave a clear and far-reaching answer in a recently published work*. But it does not yet say everything that can be said about it, nor does it include all the approaches that have already been successfully asserted in physical literature. I believe that I have reached a certain conclusion in this respect by establishing the concept of pure case.
You might also check out David Delphenich's site, http://www.neo-classical-physics.info . He has done his own translation of lots of papers on similar subjects and he might just have this (I could not find it) or even be willing to contribute it. I don't know him, but just a thought :)
